# Mass rename of pdf files using command prompt

Tags: command-line, pdf, rename

I have a client who is using there own CRM  and file naming structure and I need to change the file names to match the data in their system.

All of the pdfs will be in the same folder.
What I would like to do is pull the information from a csv "comma delimited" file and if "column A" equals "filename.pdf", rename "filename.pdf" to value of "column B".

Thank you for your time, and please let me know if you need any additional information or if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: What operating system's command line? Without knowing that, it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

ren.csv:

```
file,new
1.txt,2.txt
```

## powershell as command line:

```
powershell ipcsv ren.csv^|%{ren $_.file $_.new}
```

## cmd:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %a in (ren.csv) do ren %a %b
```

## python (crossplatform):

```
python rencsv.py
```

install `unicodecsv` module:

```
pip install http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/u/unicodecsv/unicodecsv-0.9.4.tar.gz
```

rencsv.py:

```
import os, unicodecsv as csv

with open('ren.csv','rt') as csvList:
    renList = csv.reader(csvList, delimiter = ',')
    for row in renList:
        if os.path.exists(row[0]):
           os.renames(row[0],row[1])
```

## php (crossplatform):

```
php rencsv.php
```

rencsv.php:

```
<?php
$csv=array_map('str_getcsv',file('ren.csv'));
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($csv) - 1; $i++) {
if (file_exists($csv[$i][0])) {rename($csv[$i][0], $csv[$i][1]);}}
?>
```

Comment: The OP didn't say they were using Windows.

Comment: @slhck Update, add crossplatform way

Comment: @slhck: The OP _did_ say "command prompt", which is the name of `cmd.exe`.